# How to give custom names to nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a RoR application where I want to apply custom routes names, right now I have this:

```
localhost:3000/users/:id/groups/:id
```

And I want something like

```
localhost:3000/users/username/groups/groupname
```

So far,I've been able to create the route for the user and I ended up with:

```
localhost:3000/users/username
```

I did that by adding `to_param` into my user model, but once I click to go into my groups,it goes back to the `:id` instead of the username.
I also tried to apply the `to_param` into my group model as well, but it did nothing.

These are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :groups, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
    resources :entities, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create]
  end

  root "users#index"
end
```

So I don't know how to achieve that, is the problem in the routes file? or is it within the models?

Comment: I assume you are looking for smth like this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From rails 5 you can use `:param` to specify a different identifier

```rb
resources :users, param: :username do 
  resources :groups, param: :groupname
end
```

I believe this will give you `users/<username>/groups/<groupname>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I applied this solution to my routes and then updated my queries from `find(params[:id])` to `find(params[:name])` and it is working, but not exactly how I want. It happens that if I type the URL by hand and go for `users/username/groups/groupname` it works, but if I click on any link (that takes me to the same place) it still shows the id instead, any idea how to solve that? I am using friendly now also, just in case it helps with something

Comment: How are you building the links, can you post some of that code and I will see If I can assist with that issue. Like the view - I take it you're using rails front-end

Comment: I didn't take that into consideration, my links were looking like: ` <%= link_to group.name, user_group_path(current_user.id, group.id) %>`
So that is why it was not actually working. I replaced them with `<%= link_to group.name, user_group_path(current_user.name, group.name) %>` and now they are working as expected. After modifying my links I had to modify my controllers due to Friendly_id gem as well, but not a big deal. Thanks for helping!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.